# Expected end of line etc. but found identifier-applescript

Tags: applescript

This is the command:

```
display alert "Finder can not check for virusus, continue?" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2
if the button returned of the result is "Cancel" then
    tell application "Finder" to make new Finder window
    delay 1
    tell application "Finder" to shut down
else
    delay 2
    display alert "Your mac has been corrupted" buttons {"Abort", "Continue"}
    repeat 10 times
        tell application "finder" to make new finder window"
        end repeat
    if the button returned of the result is "Abort" then
        display alert "Virusus have control of your computer, you should remove them" buttons {"Remove"} default button 1
        if the button returned of the result is "Remove" then display alert "Your mac has been destroyed"
    else
        display alert "Your mac has been destroyed"
        delay 1
        tell application "Finder" to shut down
    end if
end if
```

I am trying to prank my friends into thinking that they have a virus on their computer. But every time I run this command I always get the error: Expected end of line but found identifier. any fix?

Comment: Looks like you just have an extra double quote in there, but shutting someone's machine down isn't a very friendly prank.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a stray double quote at the end of line 10, `... make new finder window"`.  Errors of this sort are tricky to spot, because they get reported at the apparent *end* of the string, not the beginning, and AppleScript strings can span multiple lines.

That’s the technical problem.  You get to solve the social problems this script will create for you should you choose to deploy it.